# how to get a random user input variable to return in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so basically what i'm trying to do is create an html document that allows the user to input any thing they want with any number of choices and click a button and get one of the things they typed in to be chosen at random. My girlfriend is really indecisive and sometimes takes hours to make a choice when i'm not around so i thought i'd write her a code to help. I'm not exactly sure how to go about this. I have searched around for a few hours and have found nothing about this. Sorry if it's something extremely simple but any help would be greatly appreciated. So far i have this as a code to get a text box and make a new one appear by clicking the button

`

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var instance = 1;    
function newTextBox(element)
{               
instance++; 
var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
newInput.id = "text" + instance;
newInput.name = "text" + instance;
newInput.type = "text";
//document.body.write("<br>");
document.body.insertBefore(newInput, element);

document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), element);
            }
</script>
</head>


<body>
<input id="text2" type="text" name="text1"/> <br>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="New text box" onclick="newTextBox(this);" />
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

### HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Get Random" onclick="selectRandomInput();"/> <!-- select a random element among [1,instance] elements. -->
```

### JS:

```
function selectRandomInput(){
    var selectedId=Math.floor(Math.random()*instance+1);
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;i++){
        element=document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
        if(element.id!=selectedId && element.type!="button")
            element.style.display="none";
    }
}
```

**PS:** A better solution is to add a class to input text elements, and iterate over those having this class instead of all input tags.

Comment: Define "better". :-) A simpler, faster solution is to put form controls in a form, then iterate over the members of the form's *elements* collection.

Comment: Better than my solution :). Since I did not want to change the code in question, I solved the question as in my answer. But if I were him, I wouldn't solve the problem as in my post. I just wanted to make it clear in PS, tried to advise a better solution than the solution above PS.

Comment: @haitaka Thanks for the quick replies the above code is just what i have tried to work with. I don't mind if the best solution is completely different from what i have. I'm not exactly knowledgeable in coding i had a small class in html and java but that was years ago and i have forgotten most of it so i'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to code. So could you please give an example of using the form controls? thanks again for the help in the meantime ill use the solution provided by haitaka